# How to convert 18 digit time stamp to hours minutes and second?

Tags: swift

I want to show current time in an UILabel.To get current time I use following code

```
extension Date {
func toMillis() -> Int64! {
    return Int64(self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    }
}
```

And use the function as:

```
let currentTime = Date().toMillis()
```

it returns a value of 18 digits like that `1533013044694` how could I convert it into human readable format.Is there any other way get current time and date?

Comment: Date() already contains current time. Use DateFormatter to convert it to a string.

Comment: Your `toMillis()` function has no use for converting the `Date` to a human readable date. As stated, use `DateFormatter`. There are countless examples.

Comment: Unrelated but why is your `toMillis` function declared to return an implicitly unwrapped value? That `!` is unnecessary.

Comment: When reviewing the duplicate, use the answer making use of `DateFormatter` and not the answer use `DateComponents`.